# Meteor aldeed-tabular

Tags: meteor, tabular

i'm trying to get the list of all users using aldeed-tabular but it doesn't work , any help please !

**lib/Users.js**

```
    TabularTables = {};
Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);
TabularTables.UserList = new Tabular.Table({
  name: "Users List",
  collection: Meteor.users,
  columns: [
    {data: "email()", title: "firstName", class: "col-md-1"},
    {data: "lastName", title: "lastName", class: "col-md-3"},

]});

      **Client/UsersList.js**

    <template name="tabular">

{{> tabular table=TabularTables.UserList class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"}}

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/display-only-users-with-a-specific-role-in-meteor-tabular-table/20575/8) where they discuss displaying users with specific roles. Your case is easier since you just want to get all users.